# set -eo pipefail differs on ksh and bash

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, ksh

I would like like to terminate a script on any failure including inside a pipe. In bash, you can `set -eo pipefail`, but this doesn't work in ksh.

Example:

```
# x
set -eo pipefail
false | true
echo "done: $?" # reached in ksh, unexpected
false
echo "done2" # not reached in either shell, as expected
```

```
bash x        # prints nothing, as expected
ksh x         # done: 1
ksh --version # ... 93u+ 2012-08-01
```

Why would ksh not exit in this case?

Edit: Adding another test

I compared this to other shells and am getting different results:

```
-bash-5.0$ zsh -c 'set -eo pipefail; false | true; exit 2' ; echo $?
1
-bash-5.0$ ksh -c 'set -eo pipefail; false | true; exit 2'; echo $?
2
-bash-5.0$ bash -c 'set -eo pipefail; false | true; exit 2' ; echo $?
1
```

Other than a bug in ksh, I do not understand what could cause this behavior. According to man ksh:

```
-e    Unless contained in a ⎪⎪ or && command, or the command
      following an if while or until command or in the
      pipeline following !, if a command has a non-zero exit  # Pipeline does not follow !
      status, execute the ERR trap, if set, and exit.  This   # Pipeline has a non-zero exit status
      mode is disabled while reading profiles.

pipefail
      A pipeline will not complete until all
      components of the pipeline have completed, and
      the return value will be the value of the last
      non-zero command to fail or zero if no command
      has failed.
```

Comment: You may use a questionable version of ksh93. It works as expected with the ksh93 t+ from 2010 from OpenSolaris and BTW: this is the fastest ksh93 ever seen.

Comment: OpenBSD ksh93 u+ prints the done message, fwiw.

Comment: @Shawn which is not surprising, since it's the same version as the OP's ;-)

Comment: I just tried on linux as well. Version `... 2020.0.0` has the same behavior. I will update the question with another test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a regression introduced by ksh93u+. ksh93u worked as expected in that regard (and like zsh, bash, mksh, yash and busybox sh).

I've just raised the issue at https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/121

Now fixed in https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/commit/c049eec854d506ad6110eb50c769b10224c60075, included since v1.0.0-beta.1